# Trouble with lazy convolution fn in Clojure

Tags: functional-programming, clojure, convolution, signal-processing

I am writing some signal processing software, and I am starting off by writing out a **[discrete convolution function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution)**.

This works fine for the first ten thousand or so list of values, but as they get larger (say, 100k), I begin to get StackOverflow errors, of course.

Unfortunately, I am having a *lot* of trouble converting the imperative convolution algorithm I have to a **recursive & lazy version** that is actually fast enough to use (having at least a modicum of elegance would be nice as well).

I am also not 100% sure I have this function completely right, yet – please let me know if I'm missing something/doing something wrong. I *think* it's correct.

```
(defn convolve
  "
    Convolves xs with is.

    This is a discrete convolution.

    'xs  :: list of numbers
    'is  :: list of numbers
  "
  [xs is]
  (loop [xs xs finalacc () acc ()]
    (if (empty? xs)
      (concat finalacc acc)
      (recur (rest xs)
             (if (empty? acc)
               ()
               (concat finalacc [(first acc)]))
             (if (empty? acc)
               (map #(* (first xs) %) is)
               (vec-add
                (map #(* (first xs) %) is)
                (rest acc)))))))
```

I'd be much obliged for any sort of help: I'm still getting my bearings in Clojure, and making this elegant and lazy and/or recursive would be wonderful.

I'm a little surprised how difficult it is to express an algorithm which is *quite* easy to express in an imperative language in a Lisp. But perhaps I'm doing it wrong!

**EDIT:**
Just to show how easy it is to express in an imperative language, and to give people the algorithm that works nicely and is easy to read, here is the Python version. Aside from being shorter, more concise and far easier to reason about, it executes orders of magnitude faster than the Clojure code: even my imperative Clojure code using Java arrays.

```
from itertools import repeat

def convolve(ns, ms):
    y = [i for i in repeat(0, len(ns)+len(ms)-1)]
    for n in range(len(ns)):
        for m in range(len(ms)):
            y[n+m] = y[n+m] + ns[n]*ms[m]
    return y
```

Here, on the other hand, is the imperative Clojure code. It also drops the last, non fully-immersed, values from the convolution. So aside from being slow and ugly, it's not 100% functional. Nor functional.

```
(defn imp-convolve-1
  [xs is]
  (let [ys (into-array Double (repeat (dec (+ (count xs) (count is))) 0.0))
        xs (vec xs)
        is (vec is)]
     (map #(first %)
          (for [i (range (count xs))]
            (for [j (range (count is))]
              (aset ys (+ i j)
                    (+ (* (nth xs i) (nth is j))
                       (nth ys (+ i j)))))))))
```

This is so disheartening. Please, someone show me I've just missed something obvious.

**EDIT 3:**

Here's another version I thought up yesterday, showing how I'd like to be able express it (though other solutions are quite elegant; I'm just putting another one out there!)

```
(defn convolve-2
  [xs is]
  (reduce #(vec-add %1 (pad-l %2 (inc (count %1))))
         (for [x xs]
           (for [i is]
             (* x i)))))
```

It uses this utility function `vec-add`:

```
(defn vec-add
  ([xs] (vec-add xs []))
  ([xs ys]
     (let [lxs (count xs)
           lys (count ys)
           xs (pad-r xs lys)
           ys (pad-r ys lxs)]
       (vec (map #(+ %1 %2) xs ys))))
  ([xs ys & more]
     (vec (reduce vec-add (vec-add xs ys) more))))
     (vec (reduce vec-add (vec-add xs ys) more))))
```

Comment: This is not at all an answer to your question, but...implementing convolution by using Fast Fourier Transforms reduces the number of operations considerably (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084987/low-pass-filter-using-fft-instead-of-convolution-implementation, for instance).

Comment: I don't know enough about functional languages to know if this will help, but you might be interested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/803055/how-do-i-do-convolution-in-f.

Comment: @mtrw In production, this will definitely be done using the FFT; for now, though, I'd love to have a nice, functional, solution. But I'm not sure how possible that is (in Clojure).

Comment: Do you have a link to the original algorithm? While trying to make a lazy functional version is an interesting exercise, doing a pretty literal translation using Java arrays will probably be more effective.

Comment: http://www.dspguide.com/ch6/3.htm Has the original algorithm (the other version is on the other page-it's essentially the same. 

So there's no way to do this efficiently in a functional manner?

Comment: @Isaac With the coming 1.3 work this can probably eventually be done efficiently in a functional manner. But there's needs to be more support for working with Java arrays of primitive data in a higher order fashion.

Comment: @dnolen (By the way, thanks for the Enlive guide. That's what got me into Clojure in the first place.) So there's probably no way to express this nicely in Clojure 1.2? Even using `into-array` and its ilk?

Comment: @Isaac: Don't be disheartened. As far as performance an imperative version in Clojure will demolish any version written in Python. However I think what you want is still a tad misguided. Laziness is great, but not if you want raw performance. Even in Haskell laziness is avoided if you're going for perf. Be patient, with the changes in 1.3 there's a good chance this kind of thing can be - pretty, functional, fast. Remember though, be practical - Clojure and Python are similar in that regard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(defn ^{:static true} convolve ^doubles [^doubles xs ^doubles is]
  (let [xlen (count xs)
        ilen (count is)
        ys   (double-array (dec (+ xlen ilen)))]
    (dotimes [p xlen]
      (dotimes [q ilen]
        (let [n (+ p q), x (aget xs p), i (aget is q), y (aget ys n)]
          (aset ys n (+ (* x i) y)))))
    ys))
```

Riffing on j-g-faustus's version if I was doing this in the Clojure equiv branch. Works for me. ~400ms for 1,000,000 points, ~25ms for 100,000 on a i7 Mackbook Pro.

Comment: Call `(double-array xs)` on a sequence of numbers before passing as arguments

Answer (score 4):

The likely cause of the stack overflow errors is that the lazy thunks are getting too deep. (`concat` and `map` are lazy).  Try wrapping those calls in `doall` to force evaluation of their return values.

As for a more functional solution, try something like this:

```
(defn circular-convolve
  "Perform a circular convolution of vectors f and g"
  [f g]
  (letfn [(point-mul [m n]
        (* (f m) (g (mod (- n m) (count g)))))
      (value-at [n]
        (reduce + (map #(point-mul % n) (range (count g)))))]
    (map value-at (range (count g)))))
```

Use can use `reduce` to perform summation easily, and since `map` produces a lazy sequence, this function is also lazy.

Comment: Unfortunately, wrapping my `maps` and `concats` in `doalls` makes it take an unacceptably long time (I'm not sure it will finish!) to calculate a convolution with one array havign 100,000 points and the other having 2... Your circular convolution doesn't return lists of correct length, or correct values (I don't believe!) Thank you for the help, though!

Answer (score 4):

Can't help with a high-performance functional version, but you can get a 100-fold speedup for the imperative version by foregoing laziness and adding type hints:

```
(defn imp-convolve-2 [xs is]
  (let [^doubles xs (into-array Double/TYPE xs)
        ^doubles is (into-array Double/TYPE is)
        ys (double-array (dec (+ (count xs) (count is)))) ]
    (dotimes [i (alength xs)]
      (dotimes [j (alength is)]
        (aset ys (+ i j)
          (+ (* (aget xs i) (aget is j))
            (aget ys (+ i j))))))
    ys))
```

With `xs` size 100k and `is` size 2, your imp-convolve-1 takes ~6,000ms on my machine when wrapped in a doall, while this one takes ~35ms.

**Update**

Here is a lazy functional version:

```
(defn convolve 
  ([xs is] (convolve xs is []))
  ([xs is parts]
    (cond
      (and (empty? xs) (empty? parts)) nil
      (empty? xs) (cons
                    (reduce + (map first parts))
                    (convolve xs is
                      (remove empty? (map rest parts))))
      :else (cons
              (+ (* (first xs) (first is))
                (reduce + (map first parts)))
              (lazy-seq
                (convolve (rest xs) is
                  (cons 
                    (map (partial * (first xs)) (rest is))
                    (remove empty? (map rest parts)))))))))
```

On sizes 100k and 2, it clocks in at ~600ms (varying 450-750ms) vs ~6,000ms for imp-convolve-1 and ~35ms for imp-convolve-2.

So it's functional, lazy and has tolerable performance. Still, it's twice as much code as the imperative version and took me 1-2 additional hours to find, so I'm not sure that I see the point.

I'm all for pure functions when they make the code shorter or simpler, or have some other benefit over an imperative version. When they don't, I have no objection to switch to imperative mode.

Which is one of the reasons I think Clojure is great, since you can use either approach as you see fit.

**Update 2:**

I'll amend my "what's the point of doing this functionally" by saying that I like [this functional implementation](http://erl.nfshost.com/2010/07/17/discrete-convolution-of-finite-vectors/) (the second one, further down the page) by David Cabana.

It's brief, readable and times to ~140ms with the same input sizes as above (100,000 and 2), making it by far the best-performing functional implementation of those I tried.

Considering that it is functional (but not lazy), uses no type hints and works for all numeric types (not just doubles), that's quite impressive.

Comment: I appreciate that-I have virtually no experience doing imperative Clojure! Perhaps I should learn... Thanks! (Not accepting, as still looking for a functional version, but have my +1)

Comment: Though strangely enough, when I try it with 1 million points, I get an "error in process filter: Wrong number of arguments: nil, 0". Though no Java errors I can see... Works fine for 100k, though. My Python version works for 1 million - haven't tried it with more.

Comment: It should work for up to Integer/MAX_VALUE (about 2 billion) points, it's the max size of a Java array.
I'm not seeing anything different for 1 million points. Sure it doesn't happen elsewhere? "Error in process filter" doesn't sound like it comes from the convolve function.

Comment: I'll look into it some more: I also hit a Java error: OutOfMemory, or something like that. Two billion would be sufficient, I suppose, but it'd be nice to be able to use a long and have virtually no limit: there a way to do that?

Comment: With two billion doubles at 8 bytes each, you need 16GB RAM just to hold the doubles. At that scale you would probably want to look into chunking (process N numbers from xs at a time, gluing the results together at the boundaries afterwards) or laziness. I don't know of a simple, high-performance and functional way, I guess I'll have to leave that to the experts. For myself, I'm inclined to think that high-performance number crunching is one of those things that works best with mutability, if nothing else because you don't need to reinvent every algorithm you find in the literature.

Comment: I forgot my rule of thumb: think before speaking. Two billion doubles is of course sufficient. Even if it weren't, I would be using the FFT to convolve the signals in the actual application. I am still concerned that there isn't a decent functional solution, though.

Answer (score 3):

```
(defn convolve [xs is]
  (if (> (count xs) (count is))
    (convolve is xs)
    (let [os (dec (+ (count xs) (count is)))
          lxs (count xs)
          lis (count is)]
      (for [i (range os)]
        (let [[start-x end-x] [(- lxs (min lxs (- os i))) (min i (dec lxs))]
              [start-i end-i] [(- lis (min lis (- os i))) (min i (dec lis))]]
          (reduce + (map *
                         (rseq (subvec xs start-x (inc end-x)))
                         (subvec is start-i (inc end-i)))))))))
```

It is possible to express a lazy, functional solution in concise terms. Alas, the performance for > 2k is impractical. I'm interested to see if there are ways to speed it up without sacrificing readability.

**Edit:**
After reading drcabana's informative post on the topic (http://erl.nfshost.com/2010/07/17/discrete-convolution-of-finite-vectors/), I've updated my code to accept different sized vectors. His implementation is better performing:
for xs size 3, is size 1000000, ~2s vs ~3s

**Edit 2:**
Taking drcabana's ideas of simply reversing xs and padding is, I arrived at:

```
(defn convolve [xs is]
  (if (> (count xs) (count is))
    (convolve is xs)
    (let [is (concat (repeat (dec (count xs)) 0) is)]
      (for [s (take-while not-empty (iterate rest is))]
         (reduce + (map * (rseq xs) s))))))
```

This is probably as concise as it's going to get, but it is still slower overall, likely due to take-while. Kudos to the blog author for a well considered approach. The only advantage here is that the above is truly lazy in that if I ask (nth res 10000), it will only need the first 10k calculations to arrive at a result.

Comment: For your second solution, shouldn't the padding be: `(dec (/ (count xs) 2))`?

Answer (score 3):

Not really an answer to any of the many questions you asked, but I have several comments on the ones you didn't ask.

1. You probably shouldn't use `nth` on vectors. Yes, it's O(1), but because `nth` works on other sequences in O(n), it (a) doesn't make it clear that you expect the input to be a vector, and (b) means if you make a mistake, your code will mysteriously get really slow instead of failing immediately.
2. `for` and `map` are both lazy, and `aset` is side-effects-only. This combination is a recipe for disaster: for side-effecting `for`-like behavior, use `doseq`.
3. `for` and `doseq` allow multiple bindings, so you don't need to pile up loads of them like you (apparently) do in Python.

   ```
   (doseq [i (range (count cs))
           j (range (count is))] 
     ...)
   ```

   will do what you want.
4. `#(first %)` is more concisely written as `first`; likewise `#(+ %1 %2)` is `+`.
5. Calling `vec` on a bunch of intermediate results that don't *need* to be vectors will slow you down. Specifically in `vec-add` it's sufficient to only call `vec` when you make a final return value: in `(vec (reduce foo bar))` there's no reason for `foo` to turn its intermediate results into vectors if it never uses them for random access.